# jquery slideshow delays before looping back through?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple image slideshow but it's not exactly working the way I want. When it cycles through all the images, I want it to immediately loop back to the first picture. But, there seems to be a delay before it loops back which isn't what i want. How can i fix this?

here's my codepen
https://codepen.io/tayanderson/pen/vWQXbd

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seconds = 2000;
  var step = 0;
  var limit = 2;

  $("#Background").addClass("image-"+step).fadeIn(500);

  setInterval(function(){
    $("#Background").fadeOut(500,function(){
       $(this).removeClass("image-"+step);
       step = (step > limit) ? 0 : step + 1;
      $("#Background").addClass("image-"+step).fadeIn(500);
    });
  },seconds);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change limit to zero: `limit = 0;`

Even with 2 images as in your codepen example, you are starting your step  (count) at 0, and also only resetting the slideshow when `step > limit`, which requires 4 "rounds".

I've made an example of this behaviour here (see the counter): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YERNrP

Comment: You're Welcome! I Also edited the answer with an example if you would like to See the intuition. Just make sure to subtract 2 from the total amount of images as the `limit`, if you are going to put more in.